# How to access Flipgrid API?

Tags: canvas

Does anybody know how to access Flipgrid API? https://info.flipgrid.com/

Looks like they have an integration with Canvas, but no API docs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they have a full API with canvas. They do have an LTI integration that can be found at https://help.flipgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002727834-Canvas-LTI-Integration-Setup

Answer (score 0):

It appears that while they lack a complete API for Canvas, they do offer an LTI integration which can be accessed at https://help.flipgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002727834-Canvas-LTI-Integration-Setup.